# ARM deployment resourceID with servicebus not working

Tags: powershell, azure, devops, servicebus, azure-resource-manager

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my Azure Resource Package. Would love to find a way around 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument statement.

```
 [ERROR] New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:17:06 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] 'xxxxx/basket-item-changed-topic/basket-telemetry-processor' at line 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] '2799' and column '10' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current 
14:17:06 - [ERROR] function arguments 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics,xxxxxx/bask
14:17:06 - [ERROR] et-item-changed-topic'. Please see
```

-------------------This is the template

> {            "comments": "Generalized from resource:
>   '/subscriptions/fa17ed69-d83f-47bc-8604-fd96cd27d322/resourcegroups/xxxxxxx-Integration-Environment/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/xxxxx/topics/basket-item-changed-topic/subscriptions/basket-telemetry-processor'.",
>   "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
>   "name":
>   "[parameters('subscriptions_basket_telemetry_processor_name')]",
>   "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",            "location": "UK West",
>   "scale": null,            "properties": {
>   "lockDuration": "00:02:00",                "requiresSession": false,
>   "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
>   "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": true,
>   "deadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions": true,
>   "messageCount": 0,                "maxDeliveryCount": 1,
>   "enableBatchedOperations": true,                "status": "Active",
>   "createdAt": "2017-05-10T14:31:54.2059078Z",
>   "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T14:31:56.6330818Z",
>   "accessedAt": "2017-06-23T10:53:20.3815084Z",
>   "countDetails": {                    "activeMessageCount": 0,
>   "deadLetterMessageCount": 0,
>   "scheduledMessageCount": 0,                    "transferMessageCount":
>   0,                    "transferDeadLetterMessageCount": 0
>   },                "autoDeleteOnIdle": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
>   "entityAvailabilityStatus": "Available"            },
>   "dependsOn": [
>   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces',
>   parameters('namespaces_xxx_int_name'))]",
>   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics',
>   parameters('topics_basket_item_changed_topic_name'))]"          ]
>   },

Comment: are all the resources in the same template?

Comment: Yeap they are in the same azure resource template

Comment: I have also asked here but did not understand how to implement the solution. Reference https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/1965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a naming issue.

**parameters('namespaces_xxx_int_name')**

Steps to solve

1.Remove parameters from parameter file.( Use default parameters)

2.Add your functions.

3.Find all the related places that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the name of the resource <strike>if its deployed in the same template</strike>:

```
dependsOn: [
    "[parameters('namespaces_xxx_int_name')]",
    "[parameters('topics_basket_item_changed_topic_name')]"
]
```

you cannot use `dependsOn` with resources deployed or existing outside of the template, so my original remark doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Keep in mind if you just use the name - and not the resourceId, that the resource names must be unique (which is usually true but not required for resources of different types).

Comment: hey, I've never actually tried it, what would happen if I have 2 resources with the same name in the same template, would `dependsOn` fail to get parsed in that case?